# exception error in vio_ssl_write(Vio*, const uchar*, size_t) in openssl

Tags: c++, openssl

I have a decryption method which decrypts data using private key:

```
auto decrypt_private(const unsigned char* data,size_t data_len, 
unsigned char* decrypted_data)-> int
{

std::string pr_key_name="mykey.pem";
std::string keypass = "pass";
char * keypass_byte= const_cast<char*>( keypass.c_str() );

//open the private key file
FILE *fp = fopen(pr_key_name.c_str(), "r");
RSA *rsa = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(fp, NULL, NULL, keypass_byte);
if(rsa==NULL)
   ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
fclose(fp);
int rsa_outlen  = RSA_private_decrypt(data_len, data, decrypted_data,rsa, 
RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
RSA_free(rsa);
return rsa_outlen;
}
```

In main I have:

```
int main(){
std::string encrypted_data;
// encrypted data is in hex encoding
cin>>encrypted_data;
// I know the exact length of decrypted data
unsigned char* decrypted_data = new unsigned char[DATA_SIZE];
unsigned char* encrypted_data_byte= new unsigned char[encrypted_data.length()/2];
int decrypted_data_size= decrypt_private(encrypted_data_byte, 
encrypted_data.length()/2, decrypted_data);
// catch error if decryption faild
if(decrypted_data_size==-1){
     delete[] decrypted_data;
      delete[] encrypted_data_byte;
      std::cout<<"decryption faild";
      return 1;
  }
delete[] decrypted_data;
delete[] encrypted_data_byte;
return 0;
}
```

but as I add the if condition and the result of the decryption method is -1 I get error from viossl.cc :
../vio/viossl.cc:315: size_t vio_ssl_write(Vio*, const uchar*, size_t): Assertion `ERR_peek_error() == 0' failed.
and throw an exception and the program crashes. Does any body knows the reason? By the way I also removed the if condition and again I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `ERR_clear_error()` solved the problem:

```
if(decrypted_data_size==-1){
  ERR_clear_error();
  delete[] decrypted_data;
  delete[] encrypted_data_byte;
  std::cout<<"decryption faild";
  return 1;
}
```